# Can't use a file stored in my Mac as a ringtone

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, garageband, ringtones

**UPDATE** : Changed the title of the question, since I realized that the current title is a bit misleading.

I have:

- iPhone 14 Pro Max running iOS 17.3
- Garage Band on the iPhone has version 2.3.15

I have on my MacBook an `.m4r` file (which I had created from a WAV file using the online converter [www.zamzar.com](http://www.zamzar.com)), which I now want to use as ringtone on the iPhone.

I already copied the file to iCloud Drive, and I can see and play the file on my iPhone.

I found that [this guide at fonetool.com](https://www.fonetool.com/phone-transfer/get-ringtones-from-icloud-drive-to-iphone.html) supposedly describes the whole process.

Basically, it requires that after having copyed the file to iCloud Drive, I need to use the Garage Band app on the iphone to make it suitable as ringtone file.

The file is in the `Downloads` directory of iCloud Drive.

Tapping on the file from the iPhone File Manager allows me to play the sound file, so to this point the `.m4r` file on the iPhone looks okay.

Then the instruction say that for using it as ringtone, I should open Garage Band on the iPhone and tap on "TRACKS". However there is no *TRACKS* to be seen after opening Garage Band. Actually, the starting screen on Garbage Band looks completely different from what has been posted in the fonetool.com guide which I linked above. Instead of seing `<MySongs LIVE LOOPS  TRACKS` on top of the sceen, my Garage Band app shows an `iCloud Drive` file browser after starting it up.

Inside this browser, I *can* navigate to the Downloads directory, and I see there my `.m4r` file, but the is greyed out and can not be selected.

What can I do now to get things done? Perhaps the guide at fonetool.com was written with a different Garage Band version in mind?

Comment: Do you “want to transfer the ringtone to the iPhone using iCloud Drive.” or do you want to just transfer ringtone from your Mac to iPhone

Comment: @AivarPaalberg : Basicall, I want to use the ringtone on the iPhone, but I guess that in order to do this, I need to transfer the file first. I don't want to copy it over a cable, and since I use iCloud Drive already for sharing documents (PDF, ...) between the two, I thought that I could use it for this purpose too. Actually, as I wrote, the transfer itself is not the problem: The file already arrived on my iPhone, and can be played (so it arrived without getting corrupt).

Comment: Connect your iPhone to your Mac, in Finder under Locations click on your iPhone, on right pane while under General tab drag-and-drop your ringtone onto it. Dropped ringtone will be placed under Ringtones on your iPhone and can be used to set as default under Sounds & Haptics

Comment: @AivarPaalberg: How can I connect them, without using a cable?

Comment: It is possible to connect over WiFi but in order to set it up iPhone must be connected to Mac via cable [Sync content between your Mac and iPhone, iPad or iPod touch over Wi-Fi](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlada1d602/mac).

Comment: @AivarPaalberg : The general use case is that I don't want to require that both devices are close to each other. I thought a sound file is just like any other file: If I need a `Pages` document on one of my Apple devices, I copy it to iCloud, and I access it from any other device from iCloud as well. No need to have the devices close to each other. If Apple really does not allow to install a new ringtone, unless the iPhone is connected to a Mac, may I ask you to post this as answer.

Comment: BTW, the link you posted is interesting, but seems to me to be unrelated to my question. My problem is not to transfer the sound file to the iPhone - as I wrote, the file **is** already on my iPhone -, but to open this file with Garage Band and to install it as ringtone.

Comment: To get ringtone file from Mac to iPhone into Ringtones in intended way will take about five seconds. IMHO inventing new, more complicated and more time consuming ways is counterproductive.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg: You have a point here, although I have hoped to learn as a side effect, how to use on an iPhone sound files which are already stored there, and how to open a file with Garage Band. BTW, studying the link you posted in detail, I don't find information, how I can specify this ringtone file to be synced. The article just says that I should just "sync my Mac", but not **what** to sync. I certainly don't want to get any other file transfered to the iPhone as well.